# PGP certification signature file from java

Tags: java, pgp

I need to generate and sign a file with a pgp certification. My problem is the certification sign.

I have tried to use OpenPGP API (https://didisoft.com/java-openpgp/) but it looks that doesn't do anything

```
PGPLib pgp = new PGPLib();

boolean asciiArmor = true;

boolean withIntegrityCheck = false;

String privateKeyFile = "private.asc"; --> exported private key (gpg --output private.asc --armor --export-secret-key my_mail)

String privateKeyPassword = "my_passphrase";

String publicEncryptionKeyFile = "public.asc"; --> exported public key (gpg --output public.asc --armor --export my_mail)

pgp.signAndEncryptFile("INPUT.txt",privateKeyFile,privateKeyPassword,publicEncryptionKeyFile,"encrypted.pgp",asciiArmor);
```

This last command generates the encrypted.pgp file, but its not signed

---

**$gpg --verify encrypted.pgp

gpg: verify signatures failed: Unexpected error**

---

I tried to use ProcessBuilder with gpg --clearsing command, but it requires interaction from the user (asks for the passphrase in command line).

Anyone has experience with PGPLib or knows how to interact with ProccessBuilder?

I tried to use PGPLib signFile methods, and PorcessBuilder commands, but the final file is not signed when I check it with gpg --verify